# Nested if statement returning false on a few tests

Tags: java

**Given 2 int values, return true if one is negative and one is positive. Except if the parameter "negative" is true, then return true only if both are negative.**

*Here is my code:*

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {

if (negative) 
  if (a < 0 && b < 0) 
    return true;


if (!negative) 
  if (a > 0) 
    if (b < 0) 
      return true;
      else if (a < 0) 
        if (b > 0) 
          return true;


   return false;
```

[image: the bottom-most "red" result is confusing me. It should be returning true as the others are.]}

I know my mistake is somewhere hiding in plain sight. Care to point it out?

Comment: I would start by properly indenting your code and using braces for the conditional statements. The answer will become quite clear if you do that.

Comment: I was writing it with braces at first but, thinking it would help me solve the problem, deleted them, now when I try to re-enter the braces I get confused. I may just start over, that way i'll catch myself doing the error as I write the code.

Comment: You should really be using `&&` and `||`. Nesting ifs like that is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: You have a trailing curly brace *after* the table. Just another artifact of sloppy indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is incorrect for your logic. Try this:

```
public boolean posNeg(int a, int b, boolean negative) {

    if (negative) { 
        if (a < 0 && b < 0) { 
            return true;
        }
    }
    else { 
        if (a > 0) { 
            if (b < 0) { 
              return true;
            }
        }
        else if (a < 0) { 
            if (b > 0) { 
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That did it. I now appreciate curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your logic quite a bit, if `negative` is true you want to check if `a` **and** `b` are both less than zero. Otherwise you want `true` if one or the other is less than zero (which is an *exclusive or*, or *xor*). That could be done like,

```
if (negative) {
    return a < 0 && b < 0;
}
return (a < 0) ^ (b < 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    if(negative){
        return (a < 0 && b < 0)
    }else{
        return (a * b < 0)
    }
```

---

```
boolean result = negative ? (a < 0 && b < 0) : (a * b < 0);
```

[image]

Comment: `(a * b) < 0` is like asking for case with integer overflow :) Anyway it can be "simplified" more with `return negative ? a < 0 && b < 0 : a * b < 0;`.

Comment: @Pshemo jajajaja

Comment: you run the risk of overflow with large integers.